# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): conversations.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm designing the frontend of a chat application and this is the Conversations component.

The problem is on line 87 and I've highlighted the line. 'conversations' is an array so I'm unable to figure out the issue here. I'm actually quite new to react so apologies if it's something silly. Thanks!

````
const Conversations = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const [newConversation, setNewConversation] = useState(null);
  const getConversations = useGetConversations();

  useEffect(() => {
    getConversations().then((res) => setConversations(res));
  },  [newConversation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let socket = socketIOClient(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
    socket.on("messages", (data) => setNewConversation(data));

    return () => {
      socket.removeListener("messages");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      <ListItem
        classes={{ root: classes.subheader }}
        onClick={() => {
          props.setScope("Global Chat");
        }}
      >
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar className={classes.globe}>
            <LanguageIcon />
          </Avatar>
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText className={classes.subheaderText} primary="Global Chat" />
      </ListItem>
      <Divider />

      {conversations && (
        <React.Fragment>
// 87       {conversations.map((c) => (   // error on this line
            <ListItem
              className={classes.listItem}
              key={c._id}
              button
              onClick={() => {
                props.setUser(handleRecipient(c.recipientObj));
                props.setScope(handleRecipient(c.recipientObj).name);
              }}
            >
              <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar>
                  {commonUtilites.getInitialsFromName(
                    handleRecipient(c.recipientObj).name
                  )}
                </Avatar>
              </ListItemAvatar>
              <ListItemText
                primary={handleRecipient(c.recipientObj).name}
                secondary={<React.Fragment>{c.lastMessage}</React.Fragment>}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </List>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Are you sure you always get an array from `getConversations`? Try to print the returned data in the api call to make sure that it's actually an array.

Comment: Seems `getConversations().then((res) => setConversations(res));`  is updating the state with non array value.

Comment: That's mean `conversations` is `null` can't  fetch data from `API`.  You should check your `API` connection or logic inside `API`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set data which you are getting in getConversations.

setConversations(res.data)